# codeigniter table array variable not defined

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

This should be a simple passing an array to a view. The controller is set to pull all data from the table. I have initialized the table library and loaded the model code with the $this->load->model(array('Account'). I have full crud methods built.

I am getting a variable undefined on my view page.

Controller code is:

```
        public function index(){
        $this->load->library('table');
        $children = array();                    
        $this->load->model(array('Account'));
        $children = $this->Account->get();      //retrieves all the records in the database
          foreach ($children as $child){
            $account = new Account();
            $account->load($account->id);
            $children[] = array(
                $account->id,
                $account->familyName,
                $account->addr1,
                $account->city,
                $account->state,
                $account->zip,
                $account->phone1,
                $account->email,
                $account->parent_only,  
            );
          }


        $this->load->view('main_view');
        $this->load->view('body_content_ma', array(
            'body_content_ma' => $children,

        ));
     }
```

On the view page I get an error that says undefined variable children. What do you think I am missing here:

View code is:

```
           <?php 
       $this->table->set_heading('ID', 'Family Name', 'City', 'State', 'Zip', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Parent only Pickup');
       echo $this->table->generate($children);
      ?>
```

ANSWER:

This is the coding that finally worked.

I had to go back through it a few times to get it what was missing.

```
     public function index(){
        $this->load->library('table'); 
        $children = array();
        $this->load->model(array('Account'));

        $account = $this->Account->get();      //retrieves all the records in the database
          foreach ($account as $c){
            $account = new Account();
            $account->load($account->id);
            $children[] = array(
                $c->id,
                $c->familyName,
                $c->addr1,
                $c->city,
                $c->state,
                $c->zip,
                $c->phone1,
                $c->email,
                $c->parent_only,    
            );
          }

        //echo '<tt><pre>' . var_export($children, TRUE) . '</pre></tt>';

        $this->load->view('main_view');
        $this->load->view('body_content_ma', array(
            'body_content_ma' => $children
            ));

     }
```

I had a feeling that I was using $children to many times and was overwriting the variable. I was right. Once I declared the variable. I should not have used it again.

When I reassigned the variable $children to $children = $this->Account->get();
I think I effectively overwrote the array that was declared the line before. So even though the array   was filled the array reference was destroyed.

I did use the $body_content_ma in the view code to generate the table. 
Everything is being rendered now.

On to pagination!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just simple things you are missing $children variable is mapped to $body_content_ma 
just replace $children  to $body_content_ma .

```
echo $this->table->generate($children);
```

replace by

```
echo $this->table->generate($body_content_ma );
```

Comment: I wish it was so simple. I understand how it suppose to work but I must be missing a setting somewhere. Is there some config setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.. hope will be working for you.

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->library('table');
    $children = array();                    
    $this->load->model(array('Account'));
    $data['children'] = $this->Account->get();     //retrieves all the records in the database

    $this->load->view('main_view');
    $this->load->view('body_content_ma',$data));
 }
```

in view you can use $children as a array to print the value.

Comment: Tried the code above but I still get the error message undefined variable: children and if I change the echo $this->table->generate($data). I get undefined variable: data. It is like the path is incorrect and the data can't be passed.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my function;

```
    public function index()
    {        
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->model('Account_model');

        $data['children']  = $this->Account_model->get();

        foreach ($data['children'] as $child) 
        {
            // Your foreach code...
        }

        $this->load->view('main_view');
        $this->load->view('body_content_ma', $data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **`view`**:

```
<?php 
   $this->table->set_heading('ID', 
                             'Family Name', 
                             'City', 
                             'State', 
                             'Zip', 
                             'Phone', 
                             'Email', 
                             'Parent only Pickup');

   echo $this->table->generate($body_content_ma);
?>
```

**Explanation:**

You are passsing **`body_content_ma`** from your controller to your view and not **`children`** hence giving you an **`undefined error`**.

**Edit:**

Below is the format of the array to generate rows of the table.
The **`array`** should consist of **`array of rows`**.

```
$data = array(
         array('Name', 'Color', 'Size'),
         array('Fred', 'Blue', 'Small'),
         array('Mary', 'Red', 'Large'),
         array('John', 'Green', 'Medium')   
         );

echo $this->table->generate($data);
```

**Documentation:** http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice but still not right. Now my left menu vanishes and yes I check my syntax. All I did was added the $body_content_ma to the generate statement. I checked my array for content and it is not empty. I can display the array to the screen. It is fine. The explanation helps.

Comment: Can you show the printed array using `print_r($body_content_ma);`?

Comment: my mistake, I didn't loose my menu. I did the error Message: Undefined variable: body_content_ma

Filename: views/body_content_ma.php

Comment: I get content in that array

Comment: You are getting content after doing this `print_r($body_content_ma);` in  your view, right?

Comment: Yes, It prints the array to the screen the same array that is in $children.

Comment: I'm sure you are generating the array correctly. I mean when printing in view, it should have correct format. Check edits.